# Change directory before running any targets

Tags: makefile, qmake

I have the following use case where I read a variant at the top of a Makefile and then according this variable I must change directory to execute all the targets. I'd avoid to repeat in each target something like

```
my_target:
    cd $(MY_DIR) &...
```

Any approach I could use to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what you need but something like the following should work

```
ifndef submake

export submake=1
variant := somedir

$(MAKECMDGOALS):
    $(MAKE) -C $(variant) -f $(realpath $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $@

else
#actual targets defined here
foo:
    @echo $@
bar:
    @echo $@    

endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory (`cd`) where you want Make to operate, and then

```
make -f /path/to/Makefile
```